# How can I Connect to other server

Tags: php, diskspace

I want to make a platform to get disk space usage of several server.
How i can do it?

```
$df = disk_free_space("/");
```

i want this line of code to be executed on my all servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on each server, you can insert a page that returns the free space:

- http://server1.com/GetFreeSpace.php
- http://server2.com/GetFreeSpace.php
- http://server3.com/GetFreeSpace.php

GetFreeSpace.php

```
<?php
echo disk_free_space("/");
```

You can use cURL to query several servers

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://server1.com/GetFreeSpace.php',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
));

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy or maybe impossible with only php, the best solution in my opinion is send a request with curl to the server that return the disk space usage.

Comment: it might be doable if the other servers had webdav enabled, then the usage could be checked remotely

Comment: Yeah, but I think that curl is the better solution if you need only to get the free space. Agree?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `ssh2_XXX` functions of PHP to login to each server and run `df /`.

Another way is to create a web page on each server that runs `disk_free_space('/')` and echoes the result. Then you can use `file_get_contents("http://servername/disk_free.php")` to query each server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Curl is an option, you can use cron on each server, that runs at specific time and updates the value to a web server, or you can use ssh to get the same info.